Is this simple proof of Euler's Formula correct, given my definitions of e^z, sin(z), and cos(z)?
I was wondering if the provided proof of Euler's Formula is valid, or if it is a circular argument.
First, my definition of the exponential function is as follows:
$$e^z = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n \text{ for all }z\in\mathbb{C}$$
From here, my definition of sine and cosine are as follows:
$$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\text{ and }\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\text{ for all }z\in\mathbb{C}$$
This is all we know regarding sine and cosine so far because these are the definitions we gave them. From here, Euler's Formula immediately follows. Now, I state the theorem and provide the (circular?) proof:
$\textbf{Theorem.}$ For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$.
$\textit{Proof.}$ Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary. By definition of sine and cosine, we have $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\text{ and }\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$. Now observe that $\cos(z)+i\sin(z) = \left(\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right)+i\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right) = \left(\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{e^{iz}}{2}+\frac{e^{-iz}}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{2}-\frac{e^{-iz}}{2}\right)=\frac{2e^{iz}}{2}=e^{iz}$.
The proof doesn't seem circular to me, but unlike other proofs I have seen of Euler's Formula, this one seems too simple. Is it correct?

When you define sine and cosine from Euler's formula, yes, it is simple to prove Euler's from those definitions. But now everything else about sine and cosine must be proved from your definitions of them. Using your definition, how do you prove that the arclength along the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is $\theta$?

It's correct, assuming you have proved that limit exists. But ...
you do not yet know that the function $f(z) = \lim \cdots$ can reasonably be called the exponential function. You need to prove that
$$
f(z+w) = f(z)f(w)
$$
and any other properties like analyticity that you would like.
Nor do you know that $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ have their traditional meaning when $x$ is real.
Don't even think of using the addition laws for $\sin$ and $\cos$ to prove those things.
